# java hibernate @ManyToMany with composite key and common field org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for collection

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have this tables :

- tbShop with fields

  - idShop
  - idAppli
  - Name
- tbCategorie with fields

  - idCategorie
  - idAppli
  - categName
- tbCategorieShop using for relation manytomany between tbShop and tbCategorie with fields

  - idShop
  - idAppli
  - idCategorie

Entity Shop :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbShop")
public class Shop implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected ShopPK shopPK;
    @Column(name = "commNom")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany( fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name = "tbCategorieShop",
            joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "idAppli", referencedColumnName = "idAppli")
                , @JoinColumn(name = "idShop", referencedColumnName = "idShop")}
            , inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "idCategorie", referencedColumnName = "idCategorie")
                , @JoinColumn(name = "idAppli", referencedColumnName = "idAppli")}

    )
    private List<Categorie> tbCategorie ;
```

Entity Categorie:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbCategorie")
public class Categorie implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected CategoriePK categoriePK;

    @Column(name = "categName")
    private String categName;

    @JoinTable(name = "tbCategorieShop", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "idCategorie", referencedColumnName = "idCategorie")
        , @JoinColumn(name = "idAppli", referencedColumnName = "idAppli")}
           , inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "idAppli", referencedColumnName = "idAppli")
        , @JoinColumn(name = "idShop", referencedColumnName = "idShop")}
    )
    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<Shop> shopCollection;
    ...
```

Primary Key ShopPk

```
@Embeddable
public class ShopPK implements Serializable {

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idAppli")
    private int idAppli;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idShop")
    private String idShop;
... }
```

Primary Key CategoriePk

```
@Embeddable
public class CategoriePK implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idCategorie")
    private int idCategorie;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idAppli")
    private int idAppli;
```

and I have error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for collection: hello.Categorie.shopCollection column: id_appli
```

Is it possible to have common field in this entites for ManyToMany relation ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing is because the field "idAppli" is getting repeated in Shop and Categorie entities.
You can mark this field as insertable=false and updatable=false at one of the locations at should fix the issue

Comment: It's Ok, I had add update tbCategorie field in Shop.java with , insertable = false, updatable = false in JoinColumns and  same in inverseJoinColumns of field shopCollection in Categorie.java.

Comment: But I have error when insert:
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert collection: [....shopCollection#component[idAppli,idCategorie]{idAppli=1, idCategorie=1}]
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: L'index 4 est hors limites.
I had add update JoinColumns tbCategorie field in Shop with, insertable = false, updatable = false and same in inverseJoinColumns Categorie.
code : cats = new ArrayList<Categorie>(); cats.add(new Categorie(4, 1, "a1, 4"));comRep.save(new Shop(1, "com2", "name c2", cats));